# Ending a Rails 2 URL with an IP address causes routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to construct URLs in the format http://servername/find/by/CRITERION/VALUE

CRITERION is a finite set of strings, as is VALUE.  Trouble is, VALUE needs to be an IP address in some situations, and it's causing me a routing error.

Here's my route:

```
  map.find 'find/by/:criterion/:query', :controller => "find", :action => "by"
```

And the error, from the Mongrel logs:

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-05-07 10:20:32) [GET]
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/find/by/ip/1.2.3.4" with {:method=>:get}):
Rendering rescues/layout (not_found)
```

If I visit /find/by/foo/bar or /find/by/foo/1234 I don't have problems.  I suspect the problem might be Rails' inference of MIME types based on periods in the URL, but I don't really know how I can disable that.  I've tried passing a :defaults => {:format => :html} to the route but that causes Mongrel to fail to start entirely.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) worked!

My route is now:

```
map.connect 'find/by/*query', :controller => "find", :action => "by"
```

This puts everything following /find/by/ into an Array, params[:query], one URL segment per array object.  For the query /find/by/ip/1.2.3.4, this looks like:

```
["ip", "1.2.3.4"]
```

So I can just refer to params[:query][0] and params[:query][1].

If anyone has a better way of doing it, please post it!

Comment: I really liked this solution. Will star the question. Might come in handy later. :) Thanks for this.

Comment: Make sure in your controller that you are using best practices for params[:query] to avoid a SQL injection attack. In this case, I would make sure that the parameter is in fact an IP address. `require 'ipaddr'; IPAddr.new params[:query]` IPAddr will raise an `ArgumentError: invalid address` if the parameter is not an IP address.